# How can I get old version of genuine iOS images from Apple?

Tags: image, ios

Is there any way to get old versions of iOS images from Apple?

The images required to test apps. But there is no way to get this as I know.
Of course, there're some floating files on internet, I can't trust them. Because any modified image is useless for testing purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/ has images of all iOS versions.

Comment: And I believe these actually download from the Apple servers, if you check the URLs.

Comment: Greate! In fact, the files are downloaded from edgesuite.net (which is Akamai CDN) However this is trustable.

Answer (score 0):

OS X daily [also has links](http://osxdaily.com/tag/ipsw/) to a page for each iOS release that (usually in the bottom section) has direct links to *.apple.com download links for the IPSW for each supported device.